# how to solve Error : Cannot find module './routes/products' while using router on express js

Tags: node.js, express, backend, express-router

- this is products.js code path => (./routes/products.js)

```
let express = require('express');

let router = express.Router();

router.use('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.send('I am product');
});

module.exports = router;
```

- this is users.js code path => (./routes/users.js)

```
let express = require('express');

let router = express.Router();

router.use('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.send('I am product');
});

module.exports = router;
```

- this is index.js code path => (./index.js)

```
let express = require('express');

let productsRouter = require("./routes/products");
let usersRouter = require("./routes/users");

let app = express();

app.use('/products',productsRouter);
app.use('/users',usersRouter);

app.listen(1212);
```

- this is error when i try to start node./index.js how to fix this and little explanation

```
Error: Cannot find module './routes/products'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Nile-Tech\3D Objects\project\Express JS\index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Nile-Tech\3D Objects\project\Express JS\index.js:5:22)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\\Users\\Nile-Tech\\3D Objects\\project\\Express JS\\index.js' ]
}
```

Comment: Please format the code and error as code. You’ll also need to specify where your files are in the directory hierarchy.

Comment: I have formatted the code clearly so that you can give me the solution

Answer (score 0):

This error message is indicating that the application is unable to find the './routes/products.js' file.

Based on the error message, it seems that the 'index.js' file and the './routes/products.js' file are located in the following directory:
C:\Users\Nile-Tech\3D Objects\project\Express JS

Here are a few things that you can check to resolve this issue:

1. Make sure that the file 'products.js' is located in a directory
   called 'routes' and it's located in the same directory as
   'index.js'.
2. Check that the spelling of the file name 'products.js' is correct
   and    it's not typo mistakes.
3. Check that the casing of the directory and file names are correct,
   as file and directory names are case-sensitive on some operating
   systems.
4. Make sure that you haven't accidentally deleted the products.js file

If none of these suggestions resolve the issue, you can try to run the following command to check your directories, "dir /s | find /i products.js" it will search your PC to find this file.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Answer (score 0):

When you set up "use" as the middleware, in your case express will try to find another module inside your products/users.js, but since it looks like products.js and users.js was your end point you just need to set up the method to use the end point.

(./routes/products.js)

```
  const express = require('express');
  const router = express.Router();
    
  router.get('/', (req,res)=>{     // if you re using get method
      res.send('I am product');
  });
    
  module.exports = router;
```

(./routes/users.js)

```
  const express = require('express');

  const router = express.Router();

  router.get('/', (req,res)=>{    // if you re using get method
      res.send('I am a user');
  });

  module.exports = router;
```

btw you can replace all your `let` with the constant `const`